# Invariance over Galilean transformation

Tags: special-relativity, wavefunction, differentiation, galilean-relativity, invariants

I want to prove that the Wave Equation is not invariant under Galilean Transformation. I'm having a little trouble with it but this is my attempt.

**1.** First of all, **what does it mean by "not invariant"**? Does it mean that the Galilean transformation when applied to the wave equation does not depend on time?

If so, I assume I must show that the wave equation $\nabla^2u -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = 0$, where $\nabla^2 = \cfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \cfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \cfrac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ is the Laplacian, is true (its variation is not zero if $t \neq 0$). Is this correct?

**2.** I derive the Galilean Transformation: $x' = x -Vt, y' = y, z' = z, t'=t$
I'll focus only in the $xx$ direction. By doing the first derivative over $u$ I get

$$\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x'}; \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial t'} - V\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x'}$$

For the wave equation:

$$\cfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\right) - \cfrac{1}{c^2}\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial t'} - V\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\right) = 0$$

But how to go from here in order to prove it is not invariant?

**3.** The solution manual considered that $\cfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \cfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x'^2}$ and that $\cfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \left(\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial t'} - V\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\right)^2$ which is not obvious to me why it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It means that, when written in the primed coordinates, the wave equation won't read $\nabla'^2 u(t',\vec{x}') - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t'^2}(t',\vec{x}') = 0$, but rather something else and not equivalent to this.
2. Just keep performing the changes of variables to write all derivatives in terms of the primed coordinates. Notice that you can call the expressions in parentheses by the name $f$ (just to make the manipulations a bit more clear) and write, for example, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ (I am assuming your expressions for the first derivatives are correct, as I didn't check them).
3. Just as in point 2. Call the expressions in parentheses by some other name and treat them as if they were first derivatives. Then expand everything to get the second derivatives in terms of the primed coordinates.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but wouldn't you also have to transform u(x,t) to u(x',t')? In that case what do we mean by non invariant?

Comment: @JosephSanders Yes, you are now considering $u$ as a function of the primed coordinates. Non-invariant still means that the equations all look the same (I updated the notation in my answer to try to make that more clear)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now.